# Why the @font-face is always showed as unused in the Coverage tab of Chrome DevTools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

Does anybody know why the `@font-face` is always showed as unused in the **Coverage** tab of the **Chrome DevTools**?

In the example below (https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7775/webfont-sample.html), it feels like the `body` is not using the `font-family` property correctly when it actually does :(

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. See if it's reported on https://crbug.com or report it yourself.

Comment: Yes this is a valid bug, I opened a ticket: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929105

Comment: Unfortunately, it's marked as wontfix by chromium as well. You need to get the font-faces some other way.